# How to create a universal library function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, compiler-warnings

I want to manage various entities with the same "universal" functions. The entities are schematically declared as:

```
typedef struct {
  prefix_t pfx;
  int  i1;
  int  i2;
  int  i3;
} entity_t;
```

i.e. a typedef'd struct prefix for housekeeping (containing chaining pointers, flags, etc.) and a payload. There is one such type declaration per entity type.

The housekeeping functions need only to get a pointer to the prefix, which is easy, and a function which will "explore" the payload to return a meaningful quantity for the housekeeping.

With the example of binary tree management:

```
void TreeInsert (prefix_t *a, prefix_t *b, int (*compare) (prefix_t *, prefix_t *));
```

And inside the procedure, I have a call like this:

```
if (0 > compare(a, b)) {
   // a comes before b
} else {
  // a is the same as b or comes after
};
```

That's fine. The library function compiles without error nor warning.

But it is obvious that the compare function can't only reference the prefix. It needs to probe the payload to be useful:

```
int comp_entity (entity_t *a, entity_t *b) {
   return a->i1 - b->i1;
}
```

The compiler gives warning for comp_entity on the following line:

```
TreeInsert (&a->pfx, &b->pfx, comp_entity);
```

Since the library function is used for many different "entities", the compare function cannot be typecast at time of call. The arguments to the compare function cannot be typed for the prefix otherwise there is no means to access the payload.

Should I define a specific function type only for the purpose of passing the compare to the library function? Something like:

```
typedef int (func_cast *) (prefix_t *, prefix_t*);
```

and

```
TreeInsert (&a->pfx, &b->pfx, (func_cast)comp_entity);
```

I'd rather avoid this. Is this possible?

Nota:

I have found [create universal function pointer to any type C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209108/create-universal-function-pointer-to-any-type-c-language) and [How do I quiet the C compiler about a function pointer takes any number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798756/how-do-i-quiet-the-c-compiler-about-a-function-pointer-takes-any-number-of-argum), but they don't provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function knows what the true type should be, so you would declare the arguments with type `prefix_t *` and cast the arguments inside of the function:

```
int comp_entity (prefix_t *a, prefix_t *b) {
   entity_t *ea = (entity_t *)a;
   entity_t *eb = (entity_t *)b;
   return ea->i1 - eb->i1;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this solution. What I don't like is the "complication" of writing in a module dedicated to `entity_t`. We "artificially" declare arguments `prefix_t` to immediately typecast them. Without a proper comment, future maintainers will tear off their hair. Also, I don't think the compiler smart enough to realise this is a "fake" cast and I fear the total number of instruction will dramatically increase on such a smaal utility routine supposed to be short for performance reason. -- Any other idea?

Comment: @ajlittoz This type of casting is very common in callback functions like this.  If you look at the man page for `qsort` you'll see the same thing.  As for performance, that's premature optimization.  Unless you find a measurable difference, you probably shouldn't worry about it.  Also, casts typically don't have a runtime cost.

Comment: cast by itself has no cost, but we copy a to ea and b to eab. Each one is approximately the same cost as subtraction, hence a 3-fold increase. I admit it is probably not significant compared to call and return cost.

The main objection is about "software quality". When the code is read a few months from now, why were the arguments typed prefix_t to be used as entity_t? The reason is hidden under a simple `#include library.h` whose text is not visible immediately on the screen.

This is why I finally think that `(func_cast)comp_entity` in the call is preferable to coerce arguments.

Comment: @ajlittoz The function cast invokes undefined behavior because the parameter types are not compatible.  So not a good idea.  Also, compilers are *very* good at optimizing, so don't worry about the performance unless you find a measurable effect.

Comment: @ajlittoz You could also make the types of the parameters `void *` and have it work the same (you also won't need the explicit casts), and it might make the code more self-documenting.

Comment: @ dbush I tried `void *` in the libray function arg description but the compiler rejects the use of the compare function with its "normal" arguments.

Comment: @ajlittoz You still need to convert the arguments to the proper type.  You just don't need an explicit cast if you assign a `void *` to a `entity_t *`.

Comment: @ dbush I want to minimise the number of explicit casts because they usually indicate a badly designed coding. And, as you say, most indicate a possible undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ajlittoz In some cases, as with callbacks, casts are unavoidable.  What I'm describing is a well-known pattern for callbacks.  Take a look at the [man page for `qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to see what I mean.

Comment: @ dbush OK, read qsort. A bit contorted, I mean creating a "trampoline" call. Do you think gcc can handle tail-call elimination?

Comment: @ajlittoz Not sure, but again don't worry about it without a provable bottleneck.  Also, at `-O1` the above function compiles into a `mov`, a `sub`, and a `retq`.  That's it.

Comment: @ajlittoz The trampoline call to `strcmp` is just a demo to show how the callback works.  Other than that it's exactly the same as what you need to do.